# int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter chained to other channel

Tags: spring-integration

I got a spring integration FTP adaptor as below

```
<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound"
                               channel="ftpChannel"
                               session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
                               filter="myCustomFilter"                                                                  
                               auto-create-local-directory="true"
                               delete-remote-files="false"                                                                    
                               remote-directory="/app/far/boo"                                                                     
                               local-directory="file:output">
<int:poller fixed-rate="60000" max-messages-per-poll="-1"/>
</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

The custom filter is defined such a way that I get 2 files via FTP to my local directory.

Now I have requirement to send all downloaded files to next component's channel.

I have tried below for that:

```
<int:service-activator id="mySA"  method="handleMessage" input-channel="ftpChannel" output-channel="nullChannel" ref="myFeeder">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" max-messages-per-poll="-1"></int:poller>
</int:service-activator>

<bean id="myFeeder" class="com.cs.imf2.feeder.polar.MyFeeder"/>
```

When running the code, the program downloads 2 files correctly, however the handleMessage of myFeeder gets called only 1 time and 1 out of 2 downloaded files are passed as argument.

1. Why the handleMessage method does not get called 2 times as there
   are 2 files downloaded?
2. Why is the  required for
   service-activator? (Without it, I get error running the program)

Answer (score 0):

Turn on debug logging and look at the logs. Note that if a file with the same name has been processed, it won't be processed again - even if it was downloaded again. 3.0 introduces a local-filter which allows this behavior to be changed.

The adapter has a AcceptOnceFileListFilter for the local directory. With 3.0 (currently at milestone 2) you'll be able to override this filter with, say, an AcceptAllFileListFilter. This is not available prior to 3.0. Other users have worked around this limitation by separating the two functions (use nullChannel on the ftp adapter), and use a separate  to monitor the local directory. You can control the filter on the file adapter.

To delete the file, you can add an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` to the consuming endpoint (e.g. your `<service-activator/>`. See the [retry-and-more Sample](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/retry-and-more) for an example of how to use the advice, and the [reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#expression-advice).

Comment: question text modified, as few code snippets were misleading.

Comment: Turn on debug logging and look at the logs. Note that if a file with the same name has been processed, it won't be processed again - even if it was downloaded again. 3.0 introduces a `local-filter` which allows this behavior to be changed.

Comment: thanks Gary, when a file can be considered as processed? when a message with that file as payload is sent to Service Activator's defined method or when that message is read by the Service Activator?

Comment: By 'processed', I simply meant sent to `ftpChannel`. I have updated the answer with some more information about the filter.